# How to remove rows if values from a specified column in data set 1 does not match the values of the same column from data set 2 using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have 2 data sets, both include ID columns with the same IDs. I have already removed rows from the first data set. For the second data set, I would like to remove any rows associated with IDs that do not match the first data set by using dplyr.

Meaning whatever is DF2 must be in DF1, if it is not then it must be removed from DF2.

For example:

```
DF1
ID X Y Z
1  1 1 1
2  2 2 2
3  3 3 3
5  5 5 5
6  6 6 6

DF2
ID A B C
1  1 1 1
2  2 2 2
3  3 3 3
4  4 4 4
5  5 5 5
6  6 6 6
7  7 7 7

DF2 once rows have been removed
ID A B C
1  1 1 1 
2  2 2 2 
3  3 3 3 
5  5 5 5 
6  6 6 6
```

I used anti_join() which shows me the difference in rows but I cannot figure out how to remove any rows associated with IDs that do not match the first data set by using dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `paste`

```
i1 <- do.call(paste, DF2) %in% do.call(paste, DF1)
# if it is only to compare the 'ID' columns
i1 <- DF2$ID %in% DF1$ID
DF3 <- DF2[i1,]
DF3
  ID A B C
1  1 1 1 1
2  2 2 2 2
3  3 3 3 3
4  5 5 5 5
5  6 6 6 6

DF4 <- DF2[!i1,]
DF4
  ID A B C
4  4 4 4 4
7  7 7 7 7
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 6L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), Z = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

DF2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:7, A = 1:7, B = 1:7, C = 1:7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: It seems this combines the data sets (while also removing the unused IDs) and I just want to remove rows of the unused ID values from DF1 from DF2. So, I am looking to have two separate data sets that have matching ID values.

Comment: With your suggestion, I get columns: ID, X, Y, Z, A, B, and C. However, I am only looking to remove unused IDs in dataset 1 to be removed from dataset 2. All column values are different with the exception of ID.

Comment: @SarahBell Does the update work for you?

Comment: In if/then terms: if the ID number does not exist in DF1 then remove it and respective rows from DF2.

Comment: @SarahBell Your description is exactly `i1 <- DF2$ID %in% DF1$ID; DF2[i1,]` (not clear what is the issue

Comment: Your updated solution is producing a logical binary output of TRUE or FALSE. I am not sure how I can describe the solution I am looking for differently.

Comment: Before restarting rstudio, yes, the indexing was producing logical binary output. However, it seems to be working properly, so I think I was experiencing and r studio issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Load dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:6,
  X = 1:6,
  Y = 1:6,
  Z = 1:6
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:7,
  X = 1:7,
  Y = 1:7,
  Z = 1:7
)

# Include all rows in df1
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2)

Joining, by = c("ID", "X", "Y", "Z")
  ID X Y Z
1  1 1 1 1
2  2 2 2 2
3  3 3 3 3
4  4 4 4 4
5  5 5 5 5
6  6 6 6 6
```